# Firebase startup loading from database vs reading for new additions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a redux-react app listening to load all contactList when it startups and also to listen for each new contact list being added. The code below causes both the `receiveContactList` and `receiveContact` to be called at startup. How do I just have the former be called at startup and then the latter be called later when new contacts are added?

```
contactsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  store.dispatch(receiveContactList(snapshot.val()))
})

contactsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  store.dispatch(receiveContact(snapshot.val()))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The common way to split processing of initial data and new data is to keep tack of the state with a boolean:

```
var isInitialDataLoaded = false;
contactsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  store.dispatch(receiveContactList(snapshot.val()))
  isInitialDataLoaded = true;
})

contactsRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  if (isInitialDataLoaded) {
    store.dispatch(receiveContact(snapshot.val()))
  }
})
```

This will work, because the `child_added` events for the initial data are guaranteed to fire before the corresponding `value` event.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) (emphasis mine):

> **child_added**: Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. This event is triggered *once for each existing child* and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data.

So I would recommend something different: drop the first statement, and let this event fill your list on startup, while keeping it in sync as it already does. Less code overall.

Comment: the thing is that this event happens once for each child, which makes it repetitive to do it numerous times for multiple children instead of just once with the first statement